# Edit cells data of a row using Google Sheets REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-sheets-api

I have used the *Google Sheets* rest api in my chrome extension to get the data of a *Google Sheet*. Now i want to edit the data of a row in *Google Sheet* using the data I  have got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) on how to update spreadsheets.

> HTTP request
>
> ```
> POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate
> ```

Also, the [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#batch_update_operations) method works by taking one or more [Request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) objects, each one specifying a single kind of request to perform.